# gap between the bottom of the window and wood window sill

Tags: windows, sill-plate

some of my windows have this gap but others not (caulked). Some on youtube state that all sides except bottom needs to be caulked- to allow any water to escape. That makes sense but still not sure about caulking the bottom or not. Any recommendation appreciated[image]

Comment: that could be a problem. But it looks like just a frame for the mosquito net, not the window frame so not a problem other than bugs can get in

Answer (score 2):

The highlighted gap is on the outside of the replacement window frame itself. It should be there and shouldn't be caulked. This is to give an escape route to any moisture that may happen to get behind the window anywhere else.

You'll note that the wooden window sill is sloped away from the house. This helps the water run down and away instead of getting collected there, able to run any which way, or worse, sloped *toward* the house forcing it into the wall.

Answer (score 0):

The rain will get in true the mosquito net, and get trapped between the window and mosquito net frame.

The slot at the bottom is to allow rain to drain.